# Values not push in array in node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, loops, push

I am working on node.js with mongodb. I have created a array and try to push my all values but its not working. see below code.

**My Route :**

```
router.get('/loadLastdata/:rid', loadLastdata);
```

**My function :**

```
var loadLastdata = function(req, res)
{
        arrayDefine = new Array();
        History.find( {rid:req.params.rid} , 
        function(err, historyres) 
        {

            if(historyres)
            {
                for (var key in historyres) 
                {
                     console.log('########### In Loop ###############');
                     console.log(historyres[key].data); 
                     arrayDefine.push(historyres[key].data);
                     console.log('########### In Loop ###############');

                    }
                }
            }
        }).limit(1).sort({$natural:-1});
        console.log('########### Array Value ###############'); 
        console.log(arrayDefine);
        console.log('########### Array Value ###############');
    }
```

**In terminal console :**

```
########### Array Value ###############
[]
########### Array Value ###############

############ In Loop ##############
[ { __v: 0,
    _id: 57a5d4afaa21a18c247728c5,
    rid_id: '57a2029e0678a6234070e415',} ]
############ In Loop ##############

############ In Loop ##############
[ { __v: 0,
    _id: 57a5e15c86b0c2c528063b27,
    rid: '57a20d56d2472b9043052d39',
 } ]

############ In Loop ##############
```

Comment: You are checking for the array result, before for loop is getting executed. To get the actual result just add console.log(arrayDefine) just after end of for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the for-loop is defined within callback, it will run asynchronously. So add the log just after the for loop

```
  var loadLastdata = function(req, res)
  {
    arrayDefine = new Array();
    History.find( {rid:req.params.rid} , 
    function(err, historyres) 
    {

        if(historyres)
        {
            for (var key in historyres) 
            {
                 console.log('########### In Loop ###############');
                 console.log(historyres[key].data); 
                 arrayDefine.push(historyres[key].data);
                 console.log('########### In Loop ###############');

                }
            }
            console.log('########### Array Value ###############'); 
            console.log(arrayDefine);
            console.log('########### Array Value ###############');
        }
    }).limit(1).sort({$natural:-1});

}
```